# Doctrine 2.2.2 Annotated Database table relationship

Tags: doctrine-orm

I am so new to Doctrine 2 and not that good with regards to database table relationships. I understand the way of how Many to One, One to Many, One to One and Many to Many relationship works. I am just confused with this error I got below from generating database tables using the doctrine CLI.

```
  [Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]
  Column name `id` referenced for relation from Kent\Entity\DoctorSpecialties towards Kent\Entity\Doctors does not exist.
```

Please see this github link to view my entities. (Doctors.php & DoctorSpecialties.php)

https://github.com/aldee07/Doctor-Finder/tree/development-september/library/Kent/Entity

Note: I am using Zend Framework 1.11.12

Answer (score 0):

That are the annotations you must put on DoctorSpecialties class

```
@ManyToOne(targetEntity="Doctors")
@JoinColumn(name="doctor_id", referencedColumnName="doctor_id")
```

Answer (score 0):

in Many to many relationship you have to give the reference to the third forignkey table

so change this

```
/**
 *
 * @var Doctors
 * @ManyToMany(targetEntity="Doctors", mappedBy="specialties")
 * @JoinTable(name="doctor_specialties")
 */
protected $doctors
```

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I think is better you look here:
http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-2646?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:changehistory-tabpanel